# How can I access RDF-XML from Perl (or other scripting language)?

Tags: xml, perl, unix, scripting, rdf

I'm backing up my Flickr pics locally using a Perl script and the [Net::Flickr::Backup](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Net-Flickr-Backup) module. This pulls down the original picture, a thumbnail, and the associated metadata (title, tags etc) in a RDF-XML file.

I'd like to extract a subset of this metadata so I can generate a "poor man's Flickr" HTML page. This should display the thumbnail and a link to the larger version, along with selected metadata (title, tags, and the permissions set in Flickr).

I'd like to do  this from the Unix command line, pointing it to a directory of files and getting a HTML document back.

What's the best way to extract specific data from an RDF-XML file? The support in Perl seems a bit sketchy. I'm willing to try Python or Ruby if that's easier to use for RDF spelunking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the RDF-XML then you can parse it using a XML CPAN modules like one of these:

- [XML::Twig](http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-Twig/)
- [XML::LibXML](http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-LibXML/)

However you may want to look at [Net::Flickr::RDF](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Net-Flickr-RDF/) because it looks like it covers your requirement.

Comment: After reading up a bit about RDF I have a better understanding of the actual file. As a first pass, I think I'll simply pipe the file through rdfxml.py <http://infomesh.net/2003/rdfparser> and do some simple munging from the output. My primary goal at the moment is to get my pictures in a simple webpage so that I can copy the tags to my photo editing software.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I understand your question , but you don't necessarily need a [SPARQL](http://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-sparql-query/) engine to extract your metadata. If your RDF/XML always look the same, you can use a simple [XSLT](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt) stylesheet to extract a specific content from your document.